# L2TP error sending Hello (Can't assign requested address)

Tags: network, vpn

Since the Yosemite upgrade, my VPN isn't able to connect using either PP2P or L2TP protocols.
L2TP is giving me this output: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a71bf9318062543c3567
PP2P results in this output: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6e822f1f18378af0cc40

It seems that both protocols are able to connect to th server, but something goes wrong when receiving the server configuration.

I've set up the connections from scratch numerous times, tried different server locations, Wi-Fi/ethernet and so forth. Nothing helped.

Any idea how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

It appears other users are also noticing the issue https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6605525

> When using a static IP address and manual entries for subnet and
>   router in the network settings, Yosemite VPN fails to stay connected. 
>   This is probably a bug or an error that Apple needs to fix.
>
> When having the client computer (the one you are using) network settings
>   configured to either just use DHCP or DHCP with manual address, the
>   VPN connections (both L2TP and PPTP) work.  If using ARD to access
>   computers on the local network, the results are better if you select
>   "Send all traffic over VPN connection" under advanced options for the
>   VPN connection.

I just switched to OpenVPN to work around this issue.

Comment: Actually I'm using DHCP on both connections and I'm still unable to connect.